# How to remove jar from clojars?

Tags: clojure

How to remove my jar from clojars? I don't want to mess up public group namespace. I want to move myproject/myproject to org.clojars.qertoip/myproject.

Comment: This is one (of many) current deficiencies of clojars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same trouble, when I asked on the irc channel ato told me that there is no option for removing jars cause someone may be already depending on them, what he told me was that he may remove it manually if i wanted to.

Answer (score 10):

Open a ticket in Clojars' [issue tracker](https://github.com/ato/clojars-web/issues) on github. If you need it done privately (perhaps for security reasons) [email the server caretakers](https://github.com/ato/clojars-web/wiki/Contact).

If you would like to discuss the policy or help implement an alternative mechanism see [this github issue](https://github.com/ato/clojars-web/issues/9).

There are more details in the Clojars [About](https://github.com/clojars/clojars-web/wiki/about#how-do-i-delete-a-jar) wiki page

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a mechanism for doing this yourself. Consider asking Clojars admin Alex Osborne ([ato on github](http://github.com/ato)) to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to remove a jar, it however is possible to overwrite an existing jar by redeploying the same version

Comment: Hmmm. This worked for me as far as I can tell. 

I redeployed and nuked the local repo in ~/m2. When lein pulled down a fresh copy from clojars it was the updated one.

 Is this a new feature?